# node.js azure cache latency

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-caching

I am working on a node.js express application which uses azure cache. I have deployed the service to azure and I notice a latency of 50ms or so for get and put rquests.

The methods I am using are:

```
    var time1, time2;
    var start = Date.now();
    var cacheObject = this.cache;
    cacheObject.put('test1', { first: 'Jane', last: 'Doe' }, function (error) {
    if (error) throw error;
    time1= Date.now() - start;
    start = Date.now();
    cacheObject.get('test1', function (error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;
        console.log('Data from cache:' + data);
        time2 = (Date.now()-start);
        res.send({t1: time1, t2: time2});

    });
});
```

The time for `put` is represented by `time1` and `time2` represents the time for `get`.

From reading other posts on the internet, I understood that the latency should be in the order of a couple of ms, but 50ms seems a bit high. Am I using the methods properly? Are there any special settings I need to setup on the management portal? Or is 50ms latency expected?

Answer (score 0):

A few obvious things to check first:

1. Is the client code running in the same region as the cache?  The minimum possible latency is the network round trip time, which may be around 50ms between regions.
2. Is the Node.js Date.now() precise enough to measure a small number of milliseconds?  I'm not familiar with Node.js, but in .NET you should use the StopWatch class for timing, rather than DateTime.Now.